# How to display legend dynamically for line chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

In my project, legend is displaying dynamically but I want to display name like(student-marks,studentannualscore,etc..) instead of the value. Here values are displaying like 0 1 2... (instead of 0 I have to show student-marks). Here  I can't change my service values,in service values are 0 1 2 .. 
Can any one  help me how to display this using kendo ui code(javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the legend and create your own. You have more control if you build it your self. Just a suggestion.